# Use a known Maclaurin series to derive a Maclaurin series for the indicated function.

Tags: calculus, power-series

$$f(x)=x\cos(x)$$

I'm not quite sure how to do this. I did two others, which I presume is the right way to do it, as follows:

\begin{align}
e^x&=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots\\
e^{-x/4}&=1-\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x^2}{4^22!}-\frac{x^3}{4^33!}+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{4^nn!}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\sin(x)&=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots\\
\sin(x^6)&=x^6-\frac{(x^6)^3}{3!}+\frac{(x^6)^5}{5!}-\frac{(x^6)^7}{7!}+\cdots\\
&=x^6-\frac{x^{18}}{3!}+\frac{x^{30}}{5!}-\frac{x^{42}}{7!}+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{12n-6}}{(2n-1)!}
\end{align}

But where this one appears to be two separate functions multiplied together, I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Simply multiply the power series of $\cos(x)$ by $x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hints:

- What is the Maclaurin series for $\cos x$?
- Calculate the first few derivatives of $x\cos x$ in order to compute the first terms of the Maclaurin series by hand. Take note of what values you get. Write out the first couple of terms in the series.
- Using the Maclaurin series for $\cos x$ and the information you just computed, make a reasonable guess as to how to obtain a power series for $x\cos x$. Test your conjecture. Why should it be true?

If you are still stuck after these steps, I am more than happy to provide further information, but I hope these will be more illuminating than me telling you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The well known Maclaurin series is $\cos x = 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!} - \dfrac{x^6}{6!} + \dots$

We can use this as follows, (look over @AWertheim's answer before viewing spoiler)

> $$ f(x) = x \cos x = x \left( 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!} - \dfrac{x^6}{6!} + \dots \right) = x - \dfrac{x^3}{2!} + \dfrac{x^5}{4!} - \dfrac{x^7}{6!} + \dots $$

Comment: I may be mistaken, but isn't that the series for $\sin(x)$?

Comment: @AWertheim How does it look now?

Comment: @JacobMayle perfect. :)

Comment: @agent154  Yes, you are mistaken.  The series for sin(x) is $x- \frac{x^3}{3!}+ \frac{x^5}{5!}- \frac{x^7}{7!}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$.  The denominators are different.